# Finding spelling of an element in an ignore case dictionary

Tags: c#, dictionary

Weird question, but I have a dictionary created with StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase, looks something like this

AaA, 10
aAB, 20
AAC, 12

I then use myDictionary["AAA"] to find the value associated with the key, but what I also need to know is what the *actual* spelling of the key is in myDictionary, e.g. in this case I want it to return AaA. Any way to do this without a loop?
Thx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
string value = myDictionary.First(v => StringComparer.Create(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture,true)
                  .Compare(v.Key,"AAA") == 0)
                  .Key
```

Comment: The Dictionary is defined as Dictionary<string, int>
so myDictionary["AAA"] returns an integer...

Comment: Ah, you're right. I've amended the answer above with an alternative solution (doesn't take advantage of the OrdinalIgnoreCase dictionary but could be easier if you're only pulling out the key once).

Comment: I think this amended solution is still looping... the looping is just delegated to LINQ...

Comment: True, although the CLR will be optimised for this type of operation so I can't imagine there would be much difference in performance. I'll give it a try later...just for kicks!

Answer (score 1):

Change your dictionary so it looks like this:

```
public struct myValue
{
    int myInt;
    string MixedCaseWord;
}

var dictionary = new Dictionary<string, myValue>(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);

var key = "AaA";
dictionary.Add(key, new MyValue { myInt = 10, MixedCaseWord = key }); 

var correctSpelling = dictionary["AAA"].MixedCaseWord;
```